# Docker running a program as a daemon

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have a program to run inside docker (squid) that only performs as desired when it is running in daemon mode.

My question is, given a `sh` entrypoint, how can I keep the program running in background without docker exiting?

Here's my (simplified) entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# default behaviour is to launch squid
if [[ -z ${1} ]]; then
        if [[ ! -d ${SQUID_CACHE_DIR}/00 ]]; then
                echo "Initializing cache..."
                $(which squid) -N -f /etc/squid4/squid.conf -z
        fi
        echo "Starting squid..."
        exec $(which squid) -f /etc/squid4/squid.conf -YCd 1
else
        exec "$@"
fi
```

Comment: add at the end ```ping localhost 2>&1 >/dev/null```

Comment: Is squid intended to be the only/primary process inside the container?  If so, why not just run squid in foreground mode and detach the container?

Comment: because squid, if ran in foreground, loses a functionality: multiple workers

Comment: The squid multiple workers solution may better be implemented with multiple containers, replacing the master with the docker daemon, and allowing you to scale up or down based on demand along with providing rolling upgrade support. You'd just need to place a load balancer in front (the nginx-proxy image works nice for this on a single box).

Comment: I think the same thing can be achieved using `haproxy` image but the problem is that I'm losing the functionality of using different public ip addresses for connecting clients. In short, my squid box needs to run with `net: host` which opens up the ports directly and the proxy balancer won't be able to forward (or sit in front) traffic to the containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you execute a command that you want to remain running after you log out you would use the 'nohup' command as follows:

```
nohup [COMMAND] &
```

You should probably consider having squid start when the container is started. You could define this in a Dockerfile. Dockerfiles tell 'docker build' command how to create the image. This way when you start the container with 'docker run' your application will start immediately without your need for interaction with the container.

Comment: I can start it no problem. The thing is that I can only start it without being daemonized which makes it lose some features.